# GDB игнорирует точки останова

Tags: c, отладка, gdb

GDB живет своей жизнью, и периодически начисто игнорирует точки останова, особенно в случае, если они были установлены не сразу, а уже в процессе отладки. В нужную ветку выполнения совершенно определенно попадает, все сообщения оттуда в логе есть. При просмотре info, выводит "breakpoint already hit n times".
Есть ли какие-то способы настройки, чтобы это побороть и заставить отладчик останавливаться там, где надо?

Comment: Какая версия gdb?

Comment: старая, 6.1.1 для freebsd, обновить пока нет возможности к сожалению

Comment: точки останова не располагаются в shared library? Если да, то gdb может их пропускать, если переменная `breakpoint pending` установлена в `off`, или в `auto` и (что очень маловероятно) вы ответили `no` на предложение поставить ее, когда подключится либа (что-то вроде: do you wish to make the breakpoint pending on a future shared-library load?).

Comment: Как вариант, тут ( http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/How-to-enable-hardware-breakpoint-support-td101865.html ) упоминается о возможном отсутствии поддержки хардварных точек останова.

Comment: нет, точки останова в моем коде, не в библиотеке; они точно поддерживаются, так как это поведение проявляется не всегда - иногда работают, иногда - gdb игнориует их. Чаще всего игнорирует, если приаттачиться отладчиком к уже запущенному процессу, например, срабатывает первая, а дальше, при попытке перейтий к следующей, или использовать next, программа продолжает выполняться без остановок.

Comment: вспомнил древний метод: протестировать то же, но другим gdb, возможно, на другой системе. Поможет вычислить, в gdb (или окружении?) ли проблема.

Comment: Так как других вариантов никто не предлагает, вероятно проблема действительно либо в версии отладчика, либо системы. Попробую понаблюдать за ним, когда удастся все обновить...